# Unable to provision Pod in EKS cluster configured with Fargate

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks, aws-fargate, redis-cluster

I have recently setup an EKS cluster with Fargate.
When I tried to deploy Redis Service on k8s using [guide](https://ot-container-kit.github.io/redis-operator/guide/installation.html), I am getting the following errors:

- Pod provisioning timed out (will retry) for pod: default/redis-operator-79d6d769dc-j246j
- Disabled logging because aws-logging configmap was not found. configmap "aws-logging" not found

For solving the above errors, I tried the following solutions but none of them worked

- Created a NAT gateway for granting internet connection to the instances in the private subnets.
- Updated CoreDNS to run pods on Fargate. Reference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The NAT gateway that I created was in the private subnet. The private subnets themselves don't have any access to the internet. Hence, I was stuck in a loop.
By creating a nat gateway in a public subnet and then adding in the router table of private subnets being used by the EKS cluster I was able to schedule the pods

Comment: This solved the same problem to me, it's unfortunate there was no log information related to the cause of the issue